# creating new values by index in JS looping/arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, string, loops

I have an array of values:

```
let myArray = [ 'Ifmanwas',
  'meanttos',
  'tayonthe',
  'groundgo',
  'dwouldha',
  'vegivenu',
  'sroots' ]
```

I want to print out a new value for each item in the array so that the first item is a collection of all the characters at the zero index, the second is a collection of all the characters at the 1 index position, ect...

So for instance, the output of the first array would be "Imtgdvs" (all the letters at ("0"), the second would be "fearwer" (all the letters at index "1") ect...

I am very lost on how to do this and have tried multiple different ways, any help is appreciated.

For this simple attempt I have created an array of all the letters for the first instance:

```
function convertToCode(box) {


  let arr = [];
  for (i = 0; i < box.length; i++) {
    let counter = i;
    let index = box[counter];
    let letter = index.charAt(0);

    arr.push(letter);
  }
  console.log(arr);
}


convertToCode(myArray)
```

Thanks

Comment: The last string length is different, how to deal with that?

Comment: Share one or more of your attempts please. Otherwise we're just writing code for you from scratch, which isn't exactly the spirit of SO.

Comment: simply returns as best it can so the final out put would be "sseoau" and the empty value ignored.

Comment: sorry will edit

Comment: You need an inner loop also. Think columns and rows. That outer loop would traverse rows only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main issue in your example is this: `index.charAt(0);`. This will always get the first character, whereas you need a nested loop.

You could use [`Array.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) in combination with [`Array.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce), like so:

```js
let myArray = ['Ifmanwas','meanttos','tayonthe','groundgo','dwouldha','vegivenu','sroots'];

const result = Array.from(myArray[0])                              //Create an array as long as our first string
  .map((l,idx) =>                                                  //Update each item in that array...
    myArray.reduce((out,str) => str[idx] ? out+str[idx] : out, "") //to be a combination of all letters at index [idx] from original array
  );

console.log(result);
```

Note that this uses the *first* string in the array to decide how many strings to make, as opposed to the *longest* string.